Earthing connections in cascaded UK mains power supply
I've just looked at a power supply for a client to try and diagnose some other issues, and I noted that the connections weren't what I expected.
The supply is cascaded, one isolated UK mains to LV DC converter, and then one DC to DC converter stepping up from the mains to a high voltage.
Inside I noticed that the earth wire was connected to the negative voltage outputs of both converters which I think, but am not 100% sure, is not right. I think that the metal case should be earthed and nothing else. I guess if the negative outputs are earthed and a wiring fault causes a positive wire to short to the case this will have the effect of shorting the supply out, but I don't know if this is desirable. The application takes only the HV power supply (I stupidly didn't write down the exact number, but I think it's 100-1kV), and is not earthed by a separate connector. Please see the rough diagram below.

Ideally, I'd like an answer with a reference to a relevant regulation, I don't do a lot of mains applications so I'm not up to speed with them. I'm only really concerned whether this is safe, and compliant with regulations.

Depends on the application. Is it supposed to be grounded? Floating?

I'm not sure why you'd want a power supply referenced to earth, and for this application, I dont think it would matter. I'm more concerned with is it safe, is it best practice, does it conforms to UK regs?

What you show is not undesirable. The devil's in the detail i.e. what it does and how it is expected to perform and, to what safety standards it complies with (including guidance given to users and operators). All of this is missing in your question.

Some applications would require the configuration you show. Others don't.

I don't have a great deal of information, and I'm more concerned with whether is it safe, and does it comply with regulations. If the answer is "You might want to do that depending on the application, but there's no reason why you shouldn't" that's a perfectly helpful one.

How 'high voltage' is HV?  In the supply industry 240V is 'low voltage'.  If you were to have a positive rail short to the case, would the PSU(s) shut down safely (ie standard short circuit protection in the PSU)? If so, I can't see a safety problem.  There are also various questions about extraneous current paths (ie return current coming via the earth and not the ground rail, making a larger inductive pickup and collecting interference).

@user1908704, again it's a poor question from me as I can't remember. It was a very quick conversation, but I think it was in the 100-1kV range. As you say, as long as the supply can handle an indefinite short this is fine, it's possibly a good thing as it removes the possibility of energising the case from the power supply.


Inside I noticed that the earth wire was connected to the negative voltage outputs of both converters which I think, but am not 100% sure, is not right.

I'm assuming the LV-to-HV converter is a non-isolated regulator i.e. the input and output share the same ground/return.
The configuration shown in your question is exactly the same as in an ATX power supply: the outputs (5V, 12V, 3.3V, -12V, -5V) of the isolated main converter and even the standby 5V output (which comes from a separate isolated converter) share the same ground/return connection and this connection is also tied to the PE (protective earth) and therefore the entire metal enclosure (PC case).


I'm not sure why you'd want a power supply referenced to earth, and for this application, I dont think it would matter.

Shorting the output negative (or positive) of an isolated off-line converter to the PE basically eliminates the common-mode (CM) noise that can appear on the output (the CM noise here is present on both positive and negative rails and is referenced to the PE).
Shorting one of the rails to the PE may increase the earth leakage current (because the CM noise current is directed to the PE) and this may result in an unexpected RCD trip when multiple PSUs are used together. This is usually a problem for medical devices. The details are under IEC 60601.
I also noticed that the negative-PE connections is done on "multiple points" (both on LV side and HV side) which can cause ground loops (as per my first assumption above). If there are large switching currents then the entire chassis may turn into an antenna.


I'm only really concerned whether this is safe, and compliant with regulations.

Shorting one of the rails to the PE normally doesn't bring a safety problem because the main purpose of the PE connection and earthed chassis remains unchanged.
However, in your application, the negative rail of a high voltage, which can go up to 1 kV as per your comment, is tied to PE so if the HV output is user-accessible then that's a safety problem. Because, if the output was completely isolated then the shock risk would be mainly determined by the parasitic capacitances, but here there's a 100% shock risk (for a person without any protective equipment). If it's not user-accessible then it should be fine.
